# JQuery Conditional For Each

Tags: jquery, each, conditional-statements

I have this JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.descript_long").each(function() { 
        var descript_length = $("div.descript_long").text().length;

        if(descript_length < 160)
        $(this).next().("a.toggle_more").attr('style','display:none');
    else
        $(this).next().("a.toggle_more").removeAttr("style");

    });
});
```

This page has multiple divs with the class descript_long. I want this function to go through each one and for each, if the length of the text in the div is less than 160, I want the next a with class toggle_more to be hidden by setting the style to display:none. Otherwise I don't want anything to happen.

This is a sample div (of which there are several):

```
<div class="descript_short" dir="">
test
<a class="toggle_more" href="#">show more</a>
</div>
<div class="descript_long" dir="" style="display:none">
test
<a class="toggle_less" href="#">show less</a>
</div>
```

So my problem is that it's just not doing anything. I'm hoping it's a syntax error. But maybe I've written the function wrong and it's not expressing what I actually want it to do. Another set of eyes checking this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.next()` call is broken.  That's for testing siblings, not child nodes.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.descript_long").each(function() { 
       var descript_length = $(this).text().length;

        if(descript_length < 160) {
            $(this).find("a.toggle_more").first().hide();
        } else {
            $(this).find("a.toggle_more").first().show();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT** originally had `.nextAll()` instead of `find` as I had misread the OP's markup.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I have not been able to get it to work. I tested it out in JSFiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/ePhey/

Comment: @kramden88 yes, because your only `.descript_long` div has no `.toggle_more` link in it!  Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/CLXMs/

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not actually looking for the next a element, since the a elements are inside the found divs, you can use `.find()` for that purpose. Then you should use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of directly applying the style yourself, or even better adding and removing a css class you defined which will set `display:none` to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.descript_long").each(function() { 
        var descript_length = $("div.descript_long").text().length;

        if(descript_length < 160)
        $(this).find("a.toggle_more").hide();
    else
        $(this).find("a.toggle_more").show();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "this" for the text and use find.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $("div.descript_long").each(function() {          
        var descript_length = $(this).text().length;
        if(descript_length < 160)         
           $(this).next().find("a.toggle_more").attr('style','display:none');     
        else         
           $(this).next().find("a.toggle_more").removeAttr("style");     
    }); 
});
```

EDITED TO ADD FIND.

Comment: This is invalid: `$(this).next().("a.toggle_more")`

Comment: Yeah I overlooked the find.  Fixed as you were posting the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.descript_long").each(function() { 
       $(this).nextAll("a.toggle_more").css({display: ($(this).text().length < 160)?"none":"block"});
    });
});
```